# Syntax error when defining a parameter for BULK INSERT

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

In the following C# code:

```
string filePath = @"C:\Users\Me\Documents\note.txt"
var SqlSaveCommand = new SqlCommand(@"BULK INSERT table FROM @filepath", con);
SqlSaveCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@filepath", filePath));
```

I am getting a syntax error near `@filepath` when executing the sql command.

However the following does work as expected:

```
BULK INSERT proxylist FROM 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\note.txt'
```

What am I doing wrong in specifying the `@filepath` parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't parameterize the path for `BULK INSERT`. You will see the same error in Management Studio if you say:

```sql
BULK INSERT dbo.tablename FROM @wherever...
```

Also typically you need some `WITH` options there, e.g. to specify `ROWTERMINATOR, FIELDTERMINATOR` etc.

Why not build the whole command in your program?

```
string filePath = @"C:\Users\Me\Documents\note.txt"
string cmd = @"BULK INSERT proxylist FROM '" + @filepath + "';";
var SqlSaveCommand = new SqlCommand(cmd, con);
```

Comment: i don't need FIELDTERMINATOR since its only a single column data, and thanks that did it!